# useEffect with ref shows the previous state instead of the latest

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a controlled form in a functional component. I am using useEffect with useRef to prevent my validations to run on load:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    username: '',
        formValid: false,
        errorMsg: {}
});

const isInitialMount = useRef(true);

useEffect(()=> {
    if(isInitialMount.current) {
        isInitialMount.current = false;
    } else {
        validateForm();
    }
},[state.username, state.email, state.password]);


const updateUsername = (username) => {
        setState(state => ({...state, username: username}));
        validateUsername();
}

const validateUsername = () => {
    let {username} = state;
    let usernameValid = true;
    let errorMsg = {...state.errorMsg};

    if(username.length < 2) {
        usernameValid = false;
        errorMsg.username = "Must be at least 3 characters long."
    }

    if(username.length >= 2) {
        usernameValid = true;
        errorMsg.username = ''
    }

    setState(state =>({
        ...state,
        usernameValid: usernameValid,
        errorMsg: errorMsg
    }));
}

const validateForm = () => {
  const {usernameValid, emailValid, passwordValid, passwordConfirmValid} = state;

  if(!usernameValid || !emailValid || !passwordValid || !passwordConfirmValid) {
        setState(state =>({
            ...state,
            formValid: false
        }));
    }

  if(usernameValid && emailValid && passwordValid && passwordConfirmValid) {
    setState(state =>({
      ...state,
      formValid: true
    }));
    }
}

<div className="form-group">
  <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
  <ValidationMessage
    valid={state.usernameValid}
    message={state.errorMsg.username}
  />
<input
  type="text"
  id="username"
  name="username"
  className="form-control input-block-level"
  value={state.username}
  onChange={(e)=>updateUsername(e.target.value)} />
</div>
```

Then I have validations for each field. I don't really know how to explain this, but my state is always "one render behind". For example, the username validation is 3 characters minimum, but the validation only stops complaining AFTER the fourth character. How can I make sure I get the latest state as opposed to the previous one?

Comment: Isn't `useLayout` better suited for such a use case?

Comment: useLayout? I'm looking forward to know a practical use of it. @AlexTymchuk can you write an answer about the usage or point to somewhere that'd be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: The code you provided is not sufficient to give a meaningful answer. The answer would largely depend on how and when you manipulate the state.

Comment: Please update question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example. State being a render cycle behind is dependent on how/when state is updated, and how/when it is being accessed.

Comment: Just updated the question